# Problems with Running MySQL Connector in CLion

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, clion

I've recently installed MySQL Connector for CLion as I am planning to make a program that would MySQL Databases. I've installed the Connector from the mysql website and tried the code that is provided by the [website](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html). After running it, I found that it says that boost/shared_ptr.hpp does not exist. So I went to download boost version 1.66.0 and installed it into my C drive. I also added these directories into my Cmake file but they still showed errors.

This is my Cmake File:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(Learn_Cpp)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

LINK_DIRECTORIES(C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(C++ 1.1.9/include C:/Boost/boost_1_66_0)
include_directories("C:/Program Files/MySQL/MySQL Connector C++ 1.1.9/include" "C:/Boost/boost_1_66_0")

set(SOURCE_FILES "C++ Tutorials/Learn.cpp" "C++ Tutorials/ClassFile.cpp" "C++ Tutorials/ClassFile.h" "C++ Tutorials/Learn.cpp")
add_executable(Learn_Cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

I tried resolving this issue and another error showed up that I do not have a user.hpp file in boost/config.

Here is the error message:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 4
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/Boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:17:0,
                 from C:/Boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                 from C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/mysql_connection.h:31,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:9:
C:/Boost/boost_1_66_0/boost/config.hpp:30:29: fatal error: boost/config/user.hpp: No such file or directory
 #  include BOOST_USER_CONFIG
                             ^
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles\Learn_Cpp.dir\build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/all' failed
Makefile:82: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

Anyone who could provide a solution to this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**
I resolved the error "user.hpp" but I got another error message, this time regarding int32_t and uint32_t. I have no idea what these are or how to resolve this issue.

This is the error message now:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2017.2.3\bin\cmake\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\cmake-build-debug --target Learn_Cpp -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target Learn_Cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/ClassFile.cpp.obj
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Classes_and_simple_prgm.cpp.obj
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/resultset.h:30:0,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:13:
C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/config.h:95:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32   int32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/resultset.h:30:0,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:13:
C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/config.h:99:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:63:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned  uint32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/statement.h:30:0,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:14:
C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/config.h:95:19: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'
 typedef __int32   int32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:62:15: note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'
 typedef int   int32_t;
               ^~~~~~~
In file included from C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/statement.h:30:0,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:14:
C:/PROGRA~1/MySQL/MYSQLC~1.9/include/cppconn/config.h:99:26: error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned __int32 uint32_t;
                          ^~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\stdint.h:9:0,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\cstdint:41,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\bits\char_traits.h:420,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ios:40,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\ostream:38,
                 from c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include\c++\iostream:39,
                 from C:\Users\Timothy\CLionProjects\Learn_Cpp\C++ Tutorials\Learn.cpp:5:
c:\mingw\include\stdint.h:63:19: note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'
 typedef unsigned  uint32_t;
                   ^~~~~~~~
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles\Learn_Cpp.dir\build.make:87: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/C++_Tutorials/Learn.cpp.obj' failed
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:66: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/all] Error 2
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:78: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/rule' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Learn_Cpp.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Learn_Cpp] Error 2
Makefile:117: recipe for target 'Learn_Cpp' failed
```

Comment: I doubt this is salvageable. The problem is MySQLConnector was written with Microsoft Visual Studio (and it's tooling) in mind and what you're observing is one of the side effects. There are existing ports to MinGW platform, but they seem to be outdated.